# Istio Envoy rate limit not generating descriptor metrics

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-prometheus

I have implemented the global rate limiter on Istio as per this doc - [Global Rate Limting with Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#global-rate-limit) &

The rate limit service is working as expected, I can also see stats like `istio_requests_total` coming up correct in prometheus. But I can't see `descriptor metrics`, I've followed [Envoy ratelimit](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit#including-detailed-metrics-for-unspecified-values) README.md

Below are the configs for ratelimit, redis, app, descriptors & actions, that I am using.

**envoy rate limit filter**:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-ratelimit
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    # select by label in the same namespace
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    # The Envoy config you want to modify
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        # Adds the Envoy Rate Limit Filter in HTTP filter chain.
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.ratelimit
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ratelimit.v3.RateLimit
            # domain can be anything! Match it to the ratelimter service config
            domain: catalog-ratelimit
            failure_mode_deny: true
            timeout: 10s
            rate_limit_service:
              grpc_service:
                envoy_grpc:
                  cluster_name: outbound|8081||ratelimit.rtlmtr.svc.cluster.local
                  authority: ratelimit.rtlmtr.svc.cluster.local
              transport_api_version: V3
            enable_x_ratelimit_headers: 1
            disable_x_envoy_ratelimited_header: true
```

**envoy rate limit actions:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-ratelimit-svc
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: ""
            route:
              action: ANY
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        # Applies the rate limit rules.
        value:
          rate_limits:
            - actions: # any actions in here
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: "Authorization"
                    descriptor_key: "auth"
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: ":authority"
                    descriptor_key: "AUTHORITY"
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: ":method"
                    descriptor_key: "METHOD"
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: ":path"
                    descriptor_key: "PATH"

            # Action for the catalog buy prefix
            - actions:
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: "Authorization"
                    descriptor_key: "auth"
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: ":authority"
                    descriptor_key: "AUTHORITY"
                - request_headers:
                    header_name: ":method"
                    descriptor_key: "METHOD"
                - header_value_match:
                    descriptor_value: prefix-catalog-path
                    headers:
                      - name: ":path"
                        prefix_match: "/catalog/buy"
```

**Descriptor & statsd-exporter-config**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ratelimit-config
  namespace: rtlmtr
data:
  config.yaml: |
    domain: catalog-ratelimit
    descriptors:
      - key: auth
        detailed_metric: true
        descriptors:
          - key: AUTHORITY
            value: "localhost:8089"
            detailed_metric: true
            descriptors:
              - key: METHOD
                descriptors:
                  - key: PATH
                    detailed_metric: true
                    rate_limit:
                      name: default
                      unit: second
                      requests_per_unit: 1
                  - key: header_match
                    value: prefix-catalog-path
                    detailed_metric: true
                    rate_limit:
                      replaces:
                        - name: default
                      unit: hour
                      requests_per_unit: 7


apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: statsd-exporter-config
  namespace: rtlmtr
data:
  config.yaml: |
    defaults:
      ttl: 1m # Resets the metrics every minute
    mappings:
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.near_limit"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_near_limit"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.over_limit"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_over_limit"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.total_hits"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_total_hits"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.within_limit"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_within_limit"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.*.near_limit"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_near_limit"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
          key2: "$3"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.*.over_limit"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_over_limit"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
          key2: "$3"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.*.total_hits"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_total_hits"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
          key2: "$3"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.rate_limit.*.*.*.within_limit"
        name: "ratelimit_service_rate_limit_within_limit"
        timer_type: "histogram"
        labels:
          domain: "$1"
          key1: "$2"
          key2: "$3"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.call.should_rate_limit.*"
        name: "ratelimit_service_should_rate_limit_error"
        match_metric_type: counter
        labels:
          err_type: "$1"
      - match:
          "ratelimit_server.*.total_requests"
        name: "ratelimit_service_total_requests"
        match_metric_type: counter
        labels:
          grpc_method: "$1"
      - match:
          "ratelimit_server.*.response_time"
        name: "ratelimit_service_response_time_seconds"
        timer_type: histogram
        labels:
          grpc_method: "$1"
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.config_load_success"
        name: "ratelimit_service_config_load_success"
        match_metric_type: counter
        ttl: 3m
      - match:
          "ratelimit.service.config_load_error"
        name: "ratelimit_service_config_load_error"
        match_metric_type: counter
        ttl: 3m
      - match: "."
        match_type: "regex"
        action: "drop"
        name: "dropped"
```

**ratelimiter deployment yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ratelimit
  namespace: rtlmtr
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ratelimit
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ratelimit
      annotations:
        proxy.istio.io/config: |-
          proxyStatsMatcher:
            inclusionRegexps:
            - .*ratelimit.*
            - .*catalog.*
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/scheme: "http"
        prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
        prometheus.io/port: "9102"
        prometheus.istio.io/merge-metrics: "false"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: envoyproxy/ratelimit:4c088856 # 2023/03/02
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: ratelimit
          command: ["/bin/ratelimit"]
          env:
            - name: LOG_LEVEL
              value: debug
            - name: REDIS_SOCKET_TYPE
              value: tcp
            - name: REDIS_URL
              value: redis:6379
            - name: USE_STATSD
              value: "true"
            - name: STATSD_HOST
              value: "localhost"
            - name: STATSD_PORT
              value: "9125"
            - name: LOG_FORMAT
              value: "json"
            - name: RUNTIME_ROOT
              value: /data
            - name: RUNTIME_SUBDIRECTORY
              value: ratelimit
            - name: RUNTIME_WATCH_ROOT
              value: "false"
            - name: RUNTIME_IGNOREDOTFILES
              value: "true"
            - name: HOST
              value: "::"
            - name: GRPC_HOST
              value: "::"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 8081
            - containerPort: 6070
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthcheck
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /data/ratelimit/config
        - name: statsd-exporter
          image: docker.io/prom/statsd-exporter:v0.21.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          args: [ "--statsd.mapping-config=/etc/statsd-exporter/config.yaml" ]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9125
            - containerPort: 9102
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1Gi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: statsd-exporter-config
              mountPath: /etc/statsd-exporter
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: ratelimit-config
        - name: statsd-exporter-config
          configMap:
            name: statsd-exporter-config
```

**ratelimiter service yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ratelimit
  namespace: rtlmtr
  labels:
    app: ratelimit
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    - name: grpc-port
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http-debug
      port: 6070
      targetPort: 6070
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http-prometheus-metrics
      port: 9102
      targetPort: 9102
    - name: http-statsd-exporter
      port: 9125
      targetPort: 9125
  selector:
    app: ratelimit
redis deployment yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: rtlmtr
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
      annotations:
        proxy.istio.io/config: |-
          proxyStatsMatcher:
            inclusionRegexps:
            - .*ratelimit.*
            - .*catalog.*
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: redis:alpine
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: redis
          ports:
            - name: redis
              containerPort: 6379
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
```

**redis service yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: rtlmtr
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - name: redis
      port: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
app deployment yaml -

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "product-billing-ms"
  namespace: analytics
  labels:
    environment: development
    app: "product-billing-ms"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "product-billing-ms"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "product-billing-ms"
      annotations:
        proxy.istio.io/config: |-
          proxyStatsMatcher:
            inclusionRegexps:
            - .*ratelimit.*
            - .*catalog.*
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: REDACTED
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: "product-billing-ms"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /billing/healthcheck
              port: 5000
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /billing/healthcheck
              port: 5000
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
          env:
            - name: REDIS_URL
              value: "REDACTED"
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: product-billing-ms
```

I checked the existing PR & issues, and seems like it is a working component -
https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit/pull/389/files.

But it isn't working for me

Can anybody help with this ?